# Opening a image file - BLACKBERRY/J2ME

Tags: java, python, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to open an image in blackberry.

I got this in python -   myImage = graphics.Image.open(jobDirectory + "\" + name) and I wish to use this similar thing in Blackberry/ J2ME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In J2ME you can display image in following two ways:

```
Image image = Image.createImage(path_to_img+"/img.PNG");

g.drawImage(image, x, y, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);   // 1) Use drawImage function.

Sprite mainSprite = new Sprite(image); // 2) Use Sprite to display your image.
mainSprite.setRefPixelPosition(x, y);
mainSprite.paint(g);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this be the same as this myImage = graphics.Image.open(jobDirectory + "\" + name)?

Comment: What does "myImage = graphics.Image.open(jobDirectory + "\" + name)" exactly do? In J2ME by doing as above image will be displayed on screen at perticular x,y position.

Comment: It just to open a still image file without actually processing as they are purposely mutated.

Comment: When You call Image.createImage('nm') it loads the image in memory from file system. Then by calling drawImage or sprite it draws that image on screen at x,y location. You can also do any other operation rather than drawing with the Image object like moving it,making it disappear; in short you will get a reference object to that image. hope you get my point.